# TListView scrolling bug when using VCL Styles - Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, listview, right-to-left, vcl-styles, bidi

I've tried to set `TListView` control's direction to `RTL` by following function:

```
procedure RTL_LV(lv:TListView);
const
  LVM_FIRST = $1000;
  LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31;
var
  header: THandle;
begin
  header:= SendMessage (lv.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
  SetWindowLong (header, GWL_EXSTYLE,
                 GetWindowLong (header, GWL_EXSTYLE)  or
                 WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT);

  SetWindowLong (lv.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
                 GetWindowLong (lv.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)  or
                 WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT);
  lv.invalidate;
end;
```

But I have two problems as follows when the project uses `VCL Styles`:

1: `Vertical scrollbar` not appearing without clicking on it.

[image]

2: When i change the size of the ListView columns and the `horizontal scrollbar` is clicked, the following error message is displayed:

[image]

Exception source: `Vcl.ComCtrls.TListViewStyleHook.WMMouseMove`

[image]

```
procedure TListViewStyleHook.WMMouseMove(var Message: TWMMouse);
var
  SF: TScrollInfo;
  SPos: Integer;
  R: TRect;
begin
  if VertSliderState = tsThumbBtnVertPressed then
  begin
    SF.fMask := SIF_ALL;
    SF.cbSize := SizeOf(SF);
    GetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_VERT, SF);
    ScrollPos := ScrollPos + (SF.nMax - SF.nMin) * ((Mouse.CursorPos.Y - PrevScrollPos) / VertTrackRect.Height);

    PrevScrollPos := Mouse.CursorPos.Y;

    if Control is TCustomListView then
    begin
      PostMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, Integer(SmallPoint(SB_THUMBTRACK, Round(ScrollPos))), 0);
      if TCustomListView(Control).ViewStyle = vsReport then
      begin
        if (Abs(ScrollPos - ListPos) >= 1) or
        ((ScrollPos = SF.nMin) and (ListPos <> ScrollPos)) or
        ((ScrollPos = SF.nMax) and (ListPos <> ScrollPos)) then
        begin
          if TCustomListView(Control).GroupView then
          begin
            SPos := Round(ScrollPos - ListPos);
            if SF.nPos + SPos < 0 then SPos := -SF.nPos;
          end
          else
            begin
              ListView_GetItemRect(Handle, 0, R, LVIR_BOUNDS);
              SPos := Round((ScrollPos - ListPos) * R.Height);
            end;
          ListView_Scroll(Handle, 0, SPos);
          ListPos := ScrollPos;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        if Abs(ScrollPos - ListPos) >= 1 then
        begin
          ListView_Scroll(Handle, 0, Round((ScrollPos - ListPos)));
          ListPos := ScrollPos;
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
      PostMessage(Handle, WM_VSCROLL, Integer(SmallPoint(SB_THUMBPOSITION, Round(ScrollPos))), 0);
    PaintScroll;
    Handled := True;
    Exit;
  end;

  if HorzSliderState = tsThumbBtnHorzPressed then
  begin
    SF.fMask := SIF_ALL;
    SF.cbSize := SizeOf(SF);
    GeTScrollInfo(Handle, SB_HORZ, SF);
    ScrollPos := ScrollPos + (SF.nMax - SF.nMin) * ((Mouse.CursorPos.X - PrevScrollPos) / HorzTrackRect.Width);
    if ScrollPos < SF.nMin then
      ScrollPos := SF.nMin;
    if ScrollPos > SF.nMax then
      ScrollPos := SF.nMax;

    PrevScrollPos := Mouse.CursorPos.X;

    if Control is TCustomListView then
    begin
      if TCustomListView(Control).ViewStyle = vsReport then
      begin
        if Abs(ScrollPos - ListPos) >= 1 then
        begin
          ListView_Scroll(Handle, Round((ScrollPos - ListPos)), 0);
          ListPos := ScrollPos;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        if Abs(ScrollPos - ListPos) >= 0.5 then
        begin
          ListView_Scroll(Handle, Round((ScrollPos - ListPos)), 0);
          ListPos := ScrollPos;
        end;
      end;
    end
    else
      PostMessage(Handle, WM_HSCROLL, Integer(SmallPoint(SB_THUMBPOSITION, Round(ScrollPos))), 0);
    PaintScroll;
    Handled := True;
    Exit;
  end;

  if (HorzSliderState <> tsThumbBtnHorzPressed) and (HorzSliderState = tsThumbBtnHorzHot) then
  begin
    HorzSliderState := tsThumbBtnHorzNormal;
    PaintScroll;
  end;

  if (VertSliderState <> tsThumbBtnVertPressed) and (VertSliderState = tsThumbBtnVertHot) then
  begin
    VertSliderState := tsThumbBtnVertNormal;
    PaintScroll;
  end;

  if (HorzUpState <> tsArrowBtnLeftPressed) and (HorzUpState = tsArrowBtnLeftHot) then
  begin
    HorzUpState := tsArrowBtnLeftNormal;
    PaintScroll;
  end;

  if (HorzDownState <> tsArrowBtnRightPressed) and (HorzDownState =tsArrowBtnRightHot) then
  begin
    HorzDownState := tsArrowBtnRightNormal;
    PaintScroll;
  end;

  if (VertUpState <> tsArrowBtnUpPressed) and (VertUpState = tsArrowBtnUpHot) then
  begin
    VertUpState := tsArrowBtnUpNormal;
    PaintScroll;
  end;

  if (VertDownState <> tsArrowBtnDownPressed) and (VertDownState = tsArrowBtnDownHot) then
  begin
    VertDownState := tsArrowBtnDownNormal;
    PaintScroll;
  end;

  CallDefaultProc(TMessage(Message));
  if LeftButtonDown then
    PaintScroll;
  Handled := True;
end;
```

How should this problems be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this without using the VCL style?  It's obvious the exception is related to styles so the first thing is to isolate it by seeing what happens when you don't use it.  Also your screen shot cuts off the part of the math that does the division so nobody can look at it and see what the bug is.

Comment: Please show code instead of screenshots.

Comment: @BrandonStaggs yes, following my post, i have this problems only when i use `VCL-Style`, and there is no problem without `VCL-Style`.

Comment: @LURD this is a test project and all of my code is calling `RTL_LV` function,

Comment: @BrandonStaggs Regarding the math part, this code is in `Vcl.ComCtrls`, so if it really is a bug, it would be a Delphi bug which many more should be able to reproduce. But still agreed that one should never post a screenshot of code.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: So the exception is being raised when the style hook uses a zero rectangle height or width as a divisor. The question is why that condition happens, and I think it is due to you doing an end-run around the control and directly setting styles with API.  See my answer for the right approach that won't cause this problem.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems with your approach.  The quick answer is:

*Do not do this. Instead, set the controls's `BiDiMode` property to `bdRightToLeft`.*  Unless I am missing something, that will get you the behavior you need and I tested it now, there are no problems with scrolling with themes this way.

There are two big problems with the way you are tying to do this:

1. You can't guarantee the control will keep the settings you are forcing into it.  The first time the VCL needs to recreate the Window for the control, your settings will be obliterated.
2. You are assuming that the VCL doesn't need to account for this setting in some way.  Clearly it does, because you are getting bad behavior when trying to undercut the VCL and send the style directly to the Window.  If you *really* want to directly control the window style, you need to create your own descendant of the control class and handle everything related in the proper places-- you can't just pick any old time you want to change the control to RTL with a Windows API call (rather than the control's properties) and expect that the control will continue to work properly.

Comment: `BiDiMode=bdRightToLeft` Not Works on `TListView ` and `TTreeView` Controls correctly.

Comment: this is a bug in the `VCL-Styles`. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that the style hook should not ever divide by zero, but the problem is that you are changing the window styles without letting the control do anything to account for it. As I said in my answer, this doesn't work, regardless of the styling.  The VCL often needs to recreate windows, and the first time that happens, your settings which you have applied through API calls will be gone.  If the VCL control has a buggy implementation of BiDiMode then you will need to create your own custom control with corrected behavior (or post a QA bug report and wait for them to fix it).